c++20 gps_clock initilize from string
I want to set the variable of type gps_clock from a string, e.g. "2024-08-09T22:20:50".
My linux distribution uses gcc13. In this version the methods of std::chrono::from_stream and std::chrono::parse are not present.
I also haven't found a way to do it with struct tm.
How can I set the variable with this specific time?
Thanks,
Johannes
I tried already to work around this with struct tm and going via sys_time. struct tm doesn't work at all and with sys_time the seconds get adjusted (changed) (of course).

Is "2024-08-09T22:20:50" UTC, or GPS time?  GPS resolves to a calendar (currently) 18s ahead of UTC: http://leapsecond.com/java/gpsclock.htm

I'm assuming "2024-08-09T22:20:50" is a UTC timestamp.
It turns out that my assumption was wrong.  So I'll show both ways:

my_parse_utc will parse assuming the timestamp is UTC
my_parse_gps will parse assuming the timestamp is GPS

They are both pretty similar, but the second has some more involved computation at the end.
For gcc-13 you'll have to write your own parser. But that's not as hard as it sounds if you only have one (or a few) formats to parse.
The first parser will create a sys_seconds (system_time at seconds precision).  And then you can clock_cast that to gps_time:
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

// parse %FT%T from UTC string
// add error detection as desired
std::chrono::sys_seconds
my_parse_utc(std::string const& s)
{
    auto rd = [](std::string_view s, unsigned i, unsigned n)
              {
                  unsigned r = 0;
                  for (auto e = 0u; e < n; ++e, ++i)
                  {
                      r *= 10;
                      r += s[i] - '0';
                  }
                  return r;
              };
    using namespace std::chrono;
    year y(rd(s, 0, 4));
    month m(rd(s, 5, 2));
    day d(rd(s, 8, 2));
    hours h{rd(s, 11, 2)};
    minutes M{rd(s, 14, 2)};
    seconds sec{rd(s, 17, 2)};
    return sys_days{y/m/d} + h + M + sec;
}

The second parser returns a gps_seconds directly.  To get the right value it must store the time since the gps epoch, assuming every day is exactly 86400 seconds, i.e. excluding leap seconds.  Because in gps_time, every week is precisely 604,800s long.
// parse %FT%T from GPS string
// add error detection as desired
std::chrono::gps_seconds
my_parse_gps(std::string const& s)
{
    auto rd = [](std::string_view s, unsigned i, unsigned n)
              {
                  unsigned r = 0;
                  for (auto e = 0u; e < n; ++e, ++i)
                  {
                      r *= 10;
                      r += s[i] - '0';
                  }
                  return r;
              };
    using namespace std::chrono;
    year y(rd(s, 0, 4));
    month m(rd(s, 5, 2));
    day d(rd(s, 8, 2));
    hours h{rd(s, 11, 2)};
    minutes M{rd(s, 14, 2)};
    seconds sec{rd(s, 17, 2)};
    return gps_seconds{local_days{y/m/d} + h + M + sec
                       - local_days{1980y/1/Sunday[1]}};
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::string s = "2024-08-09T22:20:50";
    auto tp1 = clock_cast<gps_clock>(my_parse_utc(s));
    std::cout << tp1 << '\n';
    auto tp2 = my_parse_gps(s);
    std::cout << tp2 << '\n';
}

This outputs:
2024-08-09 22:21:08
2024-08-09 22:20:50

The gps calendar time is currently 18s ahead of UTC calendar time.  Every time we insert a positive leap second, gps ignores that leap second, but counts it as moving its calendar ahead another second.  The clock_cast and streaming operator for gps_clock take this into account.  And that's why the first timestamp is 18s ahead of the second timestamp.
gcc-13 demo.
